# Parsing couchdb _design/view result to Java objects

Tags: java, json, gson

How do I parse a _design view result to Java objects (getMethods())?

Please does anyone know how I can parse the query results elements to Java Objects instead of using a declared String? Is it possible? Several suggestions I found here used a declared String which doesn't suit to my concept.

My Document structure is like below:

```
{
   "_id": "37636ec5fc94e8e60a2744720e001441",
   "_rev": "1-cc97f6f67206667466d619901fb4eb8b",
   "CREATED_DATE": "19-09-13",
   "MODIFICATION_DATE": "20-09-13",
   "VERSION": "1.0",
   "VISIBILITY": "True",
   "PRICE_LIST_ID": "00100",
   "MODIFICATION_USER": "IKK",
   "CUSTOMER_ID": "02227802",
   "CREATION_USER": "IKK",
   "PDF_FILE_NAME": "KOOO",
   "DELETION_FLAG": "1",
   "PDF_FILE_CONTENT": "Pricelist"
 }
```

and my _design document is: **_design/VIEW_ALL_DOCS**

```
function(doc){
if(doc.DELETION_FLAG == "1" ){
  emit(doc.DELETION_FLAG, doc);
 }
}
```

Below are the view query I used for the application

```
ViewResults resultAdHoc2 = DbProperties.db.view("_design/VIEW_ALL_DOCS"); // 2
ViewResults resultAdHoc = DbProperties.db.view("_all_docs"); // 1

Gson gson = new Gson();

    PriceListDocument pld = gson.fromJson(resultAdHoc.toString(), PriceListDocument.class);     
    System.out.println("id: "+pld.getPriceListId()+" Document Name:"+pld.getDocFileName()  
               +" Original File Name: "+pld.getOriginalFileName()+" Deletion Flag: "+pld.isDeletionFlag() 
               +" Doc FileContents: "+pld.getDocFileContents() +" Visibility: "+pld.getVisibility()
               +" Doc File Version: "+pld.getDocFileVersion() +" Creation Date: "+pld.getCreationDate() 
               +" Creation User: " +pld.getCreationUser() +" Modification Date "+pld.getModificationDate() 
               +" Modification User "+pld.getModificationUser());
```

THE CONSOLE OUTPUT IS BELOW:

```
id: null Document Name:null Original File Name: null Deletion Flag: false Doc FileContents: null Visibility: null Doc File Version: 0 Creation Date: null Creation User: null Modification Date null Modification User null
```

**The output for `resultAdHoc` is below** It returned only the document header without the elements

```
{"total_rows":9,"offset":0,"rows":    [{"id":"0ecb06ce81df89c03dbedecf47001b4b","key":"0ecb06ce81df89c03dbedecf47001b4b","value":
{"rev":"2-67d92be4f768a6d91f4f4196a264897e"}},{"id":"0ecb06ce81df89c03dbedecf47002a89","key":"0ecb06ce81df89c03dbedecf47002a89","value"
:{"rev":"1-7a0c8243e56157ae1d71d3a63c49e590"}},    {"id":"0ecb06ce81df89c03dbedecf47002b81","key":"0ecb06ce81df89c03dbedecf47002b81","value":]}
```

**The output for `resultAdHoc2` is** It returned the javascript function in the design view but not the documents that matched the criteria.

```
{"_id":"_design/VIEW_ALL_DOCS","_rev":"1-8a5809780cead5e4747fb0e53ebca081","language":"javascript","views":{"VIEW_ALL_DOCS":{"map":"function(doc){\nif(doc.DELETION_FLAG == \"0\" ){\n  emit(doc.DELETION_FLAG, doc);\n }\n}"}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about your request, I try to do my best guess by the tags you provided.

What I understood is that you want to access to the elements of your JSON string that comes from somewhere. To do so, you need to deserialize your string into a POJO and then access to its elements.

Declare your POJO `Document` like this:

```
public class Document {
   String _id;
   int DELETION_FLAG;
   // more member variables...

   public int getDeletionFlag{
      return DELETION_FLAG;
   }
   // more getters/setters

}
```

and then:

```
String json = "{\"_id\": \"37636ec5fc94e8e60a2744720e001441\", ....."; // put here your string
Gson g = new Gson();
Document test1 = g.fromJson(json, Document.class);
System.out.println(test1.getDeletionFlag());
```

Comment: Yes that's the right direction. I want the `String json =` to be a query (view) results from a _design document and not an initialized string. Please do you know how I can achieve that? I tried this below but the output was returning null or 0 for the elements 
`ViewResults resultAdHoc = CouchdbProperties.db.view("_design/VIEW_ALL_DOCS");`

`Gson gson = new Gson();
PriceListDocument pld = gson.fromJson(resultAdHoc.toString(), PriceListDocument.class);
  
System.out.println("id: "+pld.getPriceListId()+" Document Name:"+pld.getDocFileName()`

Comment: Let's decompose the problem. First question: resultAdHoc variable is empty before calling Gson or not?

Comment: If it's empty you should check your query, if not would be nice if you could paste the result of resultAdHoc.toString() editing your question.

Comment: I checked in different cases and functions, the query is not null. Using `httpget`, the query returns documents in eclipse console but not when I try parsing it. Please do you know the cause? Thank you for your time

Comment: Could you post resultAdHoc.toString() into the question?

Comment: I have posted the results there. I splitted it into two, the `resultAdHoc.toString()` and `resultAdHoc2.toString()` to show the different behaviours. Maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: From what you posted, it seems to me that your query is not returning the JSON you are expecting to parse. So until you produce the right JSON there's not possibility to correctly parse. Unfortunately, I do not know couchdb. I think you could ask another question here on SO and the return back to this one.